# How to index variables using for-loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, variables, paste, mutate

I am using R, trying to change the variables in my dataframe as follows:

| Age1 | Age2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10y | 20y |  |
| 13y | 24y |  |

↓

| Age1 | Age2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 |  |
| 13 | 24 |  |

Since these variable names are labeled as Age1, Age2, Age3... I want to use the for-loop function to change them all at once.

I tried the following code but it did not work:

```
df_new <- df %>%
　mutate(
　　for (i in 1:6){
    　　  paste("Age", i, sep = "") = str_remove(paste("df$Age", i, sep = ""), "y")
　　    }
　)
```

Could you please tell me which part is wrong with this code? Any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for an alternative solution

```
df<-cbind("age1"=c("10y","13y"),"age2"=c("10y","13y")) %>% as.data.frame()

gsub("y","",df$age1)
```